# 404 Not Found. Using SQLite to enter data using SQLite

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I am new to python flask and would like to get rid of the 404 not found error. I want to insert into a SQLite table and list the items that are inserted.

> views.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
import sqlite3 as sql

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

# route for handling the login page logic
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/enternew')
def new_student():
    return render_template('student.html')

@app.route('/addrec', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def addrec():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            nm = request.form['nm']
            addr = request.form['add']
            city = request.form['city']
            pin = request.form['pin']

            with sql.connect("databsae.db") as con:
                cur = con.cursor()

                cur.execute("INSERT INTO students (name,addr,city,pin) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)",(nm,addr,city,pin) )

                con.commit()
                msg = "Record successfully added"
        except:
            con.rollback()
            msg = "error in insert operation"

        finally:
            return render_template("result.html", msg=msg)
            con.close()

@app.route('/list')
def list():
    con = sql.connect("databsae.db")
    con.row_factory = sql.Row

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from students")

    rows = cur.fetchall();
    return render_template("list.html", rows=rows)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

> students.html

```
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "{{ url_for('addrec') }}" method = "POST">
         <h3>Student Information</h3>
         Name<br>
         <input type = "text" name = "nm" /></br>

         Address<br>
         <textarea name = "add" ></textarea><br>

         City<br>
         <input type = "text" name = "city" /><br>

         PINCODE<br>
         <input type = "text" name = "pin" /><br>
         <input type = "submit" value = "submit" /><br>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

> list.html
>
> ```
>   <table border = 1>
>      <thead>
>         <td>Name</td>
>         <td>Address>/td<
>         <td>city</td>
>         <td>Pincode</td>
>      </thead>
>      {% for row in rows %}
>         <tr>
>            <td>{{row["name"]}}</td>
>            <td>{{row["addr"]}}</td>
>            <td> {{ row["city"]}}</td>
>            <td>{{row['pin']}}</td>
>         </tr>
>      {% endfor %}
>   </table>
>
>   <a href = "/">Go back to home page</a>
> ```
>
> result.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      result of addition : {{ msg }}
      <h2><a href = "/">go back to home page</a></h2>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why at list.html there is strange format of td?
<td>Address>/td<

Comment: it does not fix the 404 not found error.

Comment: When do you get the 404? Does it happen when rendering a template? Does it happen when accessing a particular endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Change your login method to this

```
# route for handling the login page logic
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

The only thing I changed was `return redirect(url_for('home'))`. You had it redirecting to `url_for('index')`, while the `index` method didn't exist.